# Updating Records In Text Files

Tags: c#

I need to create a student management system in a C# console. I have to use a text file for saving data. I can add data and retrieve data in text files but I am unable to update any student record. How can I update specific student records in a text file?

For example, my program will ask users to input a student that he wants to update then the program should fetch the complete record of that student. The program again asks the user to select the field or fields that he wants to update. After updating the field, the record should be updated.

This is my code so far, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
StringBuilder newFile = new StringBuilder();

string temp = null;
string userchoice = null;
string replacetext =null;
string update = null;

Console.WriteLine("enter the id of student to update the record");

userchoice = Console.ReadLine();

String[] file=File.ReadAllLines(@"myfile.txt");
foreach (string line in file)
{
    if(line.Contains(userchoice))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enter the data you want to replace");
        replacetext=Console.ReadLine();

        if(line.Contains(update)){
            Console.WriteLine("enter the data you want to replace with");
            update=Console.ReadLine();
            temp=line.Replace(replacetext,update);
            newFile.Append(temp+"\r\n");
            continue;
        }
        newFile.Append(line+"\r\n");
    }
    File.WriteAllText(@"myfile.txt",newFile.ToString());
}
```

Comment: DO NOT USE ALL CAPITAL LETTERS EITHER IN THE TITLE OR IN YOUR TEXT. IT MAKES IT LOOK LIKE YOU ARE YELLING, AND YOU WILL BE IGNORED. Thanks.

Comment: I don't suppose "use a library that does this for you" is an option? (e.g. a BDB-style or in-memory SQL, such as SQLite)

Comment: can you explain what is the problem with your code?

Comment: Hell, those student management systems are popular these days. They weren't at the time I was at university :-)

Comment: Not to be a jerk, but why not do your own homework?  This is very simple and part of the exercise is working your way though it and coming up with your own 'eureka' moment which is more important than simply getting the answer correct.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest handling updates in a textfile by reading the whole textfile into memory, do the changes as needed to the in-memory data. Then write it to a temporary filename, delete the original file and rename the temporary file to the real filename.
This way you guard somewhat against file corruption (if the app crashes in the middle of updating the file, the original will be ok) and you can use the same code for adding and updating the contents.

Btw, you can use the `AppendLine` method of `StringBuilder` so you don't have to add `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

If your data has some sort of structure to it, I would probably read it into a DataTable, do my updating/adding/deleting in memory, then write out a new file when the program exits or the user asks to save.

You can easily do this with XML and DataSets, as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would define a "student" object.

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set;}
    // etc etc
}
```

Second, I'd use `List<Student>` to keep track of all students in the system.

Third, I would use XML Serialization to persist to disk, for retrevial upon program load. After all, XML is just text.

Answer (score 0):

replace  if(line.Contains(update)) to if(line.Contains(replacetext))